# Deletar imagem do BD e da pasta de destino do servidor

Tags: php, html

Estou querendo excluir simultaneamente imagens de uma coluna especifica ("logo") de uma tabela com mais 05 colunas, e da pasta ("upload") de destino do servidor.

Mas só consegui ate o momento excluir não só a coluna ("logo") como todas as outras 05 colunas da tabela do BD, ou seja, excluindo toda linha, sem excluir o arquivo de imagem referente a tabela da pasta ("upload") de destino.

Estou usando o script abaixo:

```
        <?php 
        include 'conexao.php';

        $pasta = 'upload/';

        if (isset($_POST['deletar'])){
        $check = @$_POST['apagar'];
        foreach($check as $logo){
        $delcheck = mysql_query("DELETE FROM topo WHERE logo = '$logo'") or die (mysql_error());
        unlink($pasta.$delcheck['logo']);
        if ($delcheck >= '1'){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Deletado com sucesso!");
        window.location.href = "listar.php";
        </script>';
        }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Erro, tente novamente!");
        window.location.href = "listar.php";
        </script>';
        }
        }
        }
        ?>

        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br />
        <?php
        include 'conexao.php';
        $seleciona = "SELECT * FROM topo";
        $queryum = mysql_query($seleciona);
        while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($queryum)){
        $logo = $list['logo'];
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $logo; ?>" readonly><?php echo $logo; ?><br />
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="deletar" value="Excluir"><br />
        </form>
```

Tem como eu excluir dados de uma só coluna da tabela, sem exclui-la por completo?

Alguém poderia me informar se isso é possível, e se for como devo fazer?

Desde já meus agradecimentos.

Comment: Ja que vc não quer excluir a linha e sim apenas valores que estão na coluna vc faz um update tabela set logo="" where logo="nome_a_ser_excluido". Assim todas as linhas que tiverem esse valor que quer excluir ficaram vazios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porquê em vez de usar `delete` não usar `update`?

```
$delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE topo SET logo="" WHERE logo = '$logo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
unlink($pasta_imgs.'/'.$logo);
```

Ai ele vai deixar vazio na coluna onde tiver o valor da variável `$logo`.

Comment: Olá Thalles Daniel, gostaria de agradece-lo pela dica, pois funcionou perfeito, só alterei o **unlink($pasta_imgs.'/'.$logo);** para **unlink($pasta.'/'.$logo);**. Mais uma vez BRIGADÃO.

Comment: Poderia votar positivamente alguém fez o favor de negativar não sei porquê a resposta